# Extract coefficients and terms in polynomial expansion

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, coefficients

I have a polynomial in $a$ and $b$:

$$(Aa^2 + Bb^2 + Ca + Db + E)^m$$

How can I construct a table of coefficients corresponding to all different products $a^i b^j$ in the expansion for a defined $m$, and another table with the entries $i,j$ so that it is easy to track which coefficient corresponds to which term?

Comment: Can you show why `Collect` doesn't provide what you want or how to get what you want?

Comment: Have you seen `CoefficientArrays` or `CoefficientRules`?

Comment: @MichaelE2, I wasn't aware of `CoefficientRules` and that assigns the correct coefficients to all monomials as required

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for m==2:

```
m = 2;
ex = (c20  a^2 + c02 b^2 + c10 a + c01 b + c00)^m;
TableForm[CoefficientList[ex, {a, b}] , 
 TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 2 m], Range[0, 2 m]}]
```

[image]